# In spring boot, where I give produces = {"text/html","app/json"}. Is there any way to check what is being selected from the Swagger I

Tags: spring, spring-boot, swagger-ui

In controller ->

```
...produces = {"text/html","application/json"}, consumes = {"application/json"})
```

I want to check if the user has checked text/html or app/json from the Swagger UI

Answer (score 0):

User cannot choose one of the `produces` options. There should be a flag you pass to the controller which defines whether the controller returns json or html.